# Add authorization to php api for android app

Tags: php, android, security, phpmyadmin, authorization

I've created an API in PHP and I'm using it to fetch data in my android app. The app also passes a hardcoded key to server while calling the API, which checks if it is authentic (value is correct) and then returns a response.

The problem is, some geeks are decompiling my app to find the key and then making the API calls, and even selling the API to others.

If I store the key on server and call the API URL directly which would authorize the key from server, then they would also call the same URL to access the API (they can get to know the URL by decompiling APK).

I'm also using proguard in my app for obfuscation but key and URL strings can still be decoded.

So how do I add an authorization to API to verify if request is coming from my app only and not any other source. I know there must be some standard security provision for this as this seems to be the most basic need for any application